# Update data frame in R with another one

Tags: r

I have two data frames. Df1 that is the main one and Df2 that is updated one. I am trying to get value from df2 to df1 but anyting I do seems not to me working. Match / merge gives NAs and all sort of join commands do not work either.

```
V1 <- c("AB1002017103", "AB1002017103", "AB1002017103"
,"AB1002017104"
,"AB1002017105"
,"AB1002017106"
,"AB1002017107"
,"AB1002017108"
,"AB1002017109"
,"AB1002017111")
V2 <- c(249,242,253,211,264,237,291,286,232,0)
df1 <- data.frame(V1,V2)
df1$V1 <- as.character(as.factor(df1$V1))

V1 <- c("AB1002017111"); V2 <- 165
df2 <- data.frame(V1,V2)
df2$V1 <- as.character(as.factor(df2$V1))
```

The output should be all from df1 with the last value 165. Any ideas please? Just and example of the match I use:

```
df1$V2 <- df2$V2[match(df1$V1,df2$V1)]
```

Comment: by default, if there are no matches, `match` return NA, use `nomatch = 0` and also do the same index on the lhs i.e. `df1$V2[match(df2$V1,df1$V1)]  <-  df2$V2[match(df1$V1,df2$V1, nomatch = 0)]`

Comment: Thanks for that. It works like magic on my simple example however when I use for the whole datasets it gives the error "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments". Any idea why? Checked str and compared values and the seem to be idenical for V1.

Comment: As I mentioned you need `nomatch=0`.  Are the lengths same i.e for the two `match`.  Please check the output of each match.

Comment: I have got nomatch set to 0 and still nil luck.  In my original example the length was different as well, was not it? Here I have the df1 with 597 and df2 with 2308 rows however V1 is the same length for both 197 rows. Df1 has 0s for V2 and df2 has correct V2 I want to copy to df1. I need something like vlookup in excel. P.S. How to check  the output of each match?

Comment: I meant type `match(df2$V1,df1$V1)` and `match(df1$V1,df2$V1, nomatch = 0)` check whether there are NA in first case and lengths of non-zero elements are the same

Comment: They are. After I typed `match(df2$V1,df1$V1)` I can see few NAs and after I typed `match(df1$V1,df2$V1, nomatch = 0)` I can see good few 0s. Any way to overcome it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158858/discussion-between-kalenji-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

Based on help from akrun (much appreciated) below code was found working.

`df1$V2[match(df2$V1,df1$V1, nomatch=0)] <- df2$V2[match(df1$V1,df2$V1, nomatch = 0)]`

Thanks again akrun!